# SocketAsyncEventArgs and few accepts per second

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, socketasynceventargs

I am using SocketAsyncEventArgs and I can perform only a few accepts per second (I do not know why).

How can I maximize number of accepts per second? Should I call Accept(null) multiple times?

Code:
After calling Listen on the listening socket I call Accept(null) and this is my code:

```
void Accept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg)
{
    if (acceptEventArg == null)
    {
        acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        acceptEventArg.Completed += AcceptCompleted;
    }
    else
    {
        // socket must be cleared since the context object is being reused
        acceptEventArg.AcceptSocket = null;
    }

    bool willRaiseEvent = _listener.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
    {
        Accepted(acceptEventArg);
    }
}

void AcceptCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (_onAccepted != null) _onAccepted(e);
}

void Accepted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.AcceptSocket.Connected) return;

    //1
    var acceptSocket = e.AcceptSocket;
    var readEventArgs = CreateArg(null, e.AcceptSocket, null);

    bool willRaiseEvent = true;
    if (acceptSocket.Connected)
        willRaiseEvent = acceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);

    //2
    Accept(e);

    //3
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
    {
        Received(readEventArgs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a connection limit by default. You can change it using the DefaultConnectionLimit
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider it but I don't think that would be my problem. Because we are developing a sync. and thread-based TCP server and we do not have this problem using sync. methods of Socket class.